# How to get a distinct result for list of array?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of long type array.

```
List<ulong[]> TestList = new List<ulong[]>();
```

and list has following items.

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6},
{2,3,4,5,6,7},
{3,4,5,6,7,8},
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

and expected distinct result is

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6},
{2,3,4,5,6,7},
{3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

So I try as following, but useless.

```
TestList = TestList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Am I need something special comparer for getting distinct list?

Comment: You can use Except method against 2 list to see if they match exactly

Comment: What do you mean by "useless"?

Comment: @ScottHunter "useless" means "not work properly"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Distinct()` uses the default equality check, which for arrays is reference equality. It does not check the *contents* of the array for equality.

If you want to do that, you'll need the overload of `Distinct()` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. This allows you to customize the behaviour to determine if two items are equal or not.

For comparing arrays, `IStructuralEquatable` and friends already do the heavy lifting. You can wrap it simply, like so:

```
sealed class StructuralComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> Instance { get; } = new StructuralComparer<T>();

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        => StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(x, y);

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        => StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```

Then, use it in the `Distinct()` call like this:

```
TestList = TestList.Distinct(StructuralComparer<ulong[]>.Instance).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an equality comparer, default implementation does not know how to compare arrays of `long` (it uses reference equality):

```
class LongArrayComparer : EqualityComparer<long[]> 
{
    public override bool Equals(long[] a1, long[] a2)
    {
        if (a1 == null && a2 == null)
            return true;
        else if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
            return false;

        return a1.SequenceEqual(a2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(long[] arr)
    {
        long hCode = arr.Aggregate(0, (acc, it) => acc ^ it);
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
TestList = TestList.Distinct(new LongArrayComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ulong[]> TestList = new List<ulong[]>() {
    new ulong[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6},
    new ulong[]{ 2,3,4,5,6,7},
    new ulong[]{ 3,4,5,6,7,8},
    new ulong[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6}
};

var result = TestList.GroupBy(x => String.Join(",", x))
                     .Select(x => x.First().ToArray())
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I've updated your approach to `ToArray()` for the nested items - feel free to roll back. +1 for an alternative approach to `IEqualityComparer` even if this isn't that good in matters of performance

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an IEqualityComparer

```
public class IntArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        var shared = x.Intersect(y);
        return x.Length == y.Length && shared.Count() == x.Length;;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        int hashCode=obj.Length;
        for(int i=0;i<obj.Length;++i)
        {
          hashCode=unchecked(hashCode*314159 +obj[i]);
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then can implement it:

```
TestList = TestList.Distinct(new IntArrayComparer()).ToList();
```